# Taking a snapshot/screenshot of a certain portion of a screen (javaFX)

Tags: image, javafx, screenshot, clipboard, scenebuilder

I want to be able to take a screenshot of a certain part of a scene in javaFX. [Here is an image of what the scene looks like](https://gyazo.com/a4f537b77ff843da258454f5a152ade4). I want to enter parameters (such as the size of the area and where the area will be) that mean that only the graph is screenshotted/snpashotted. However the graph itself is made up of labels and images.
When it is screenshotted, I would like to save the screenshot, by either a WritableImage or copying it to clipboard, whichever is easier.
How would I do this? If you need to know, I am using scene builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as your whole 'graph', including all its labels and such, is a [javafx.scene.Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html), you can use the `snapshot` function.

If they aren't already in the same node, consider adding them all as children of a `Group`, `Parent` or `Region`.

The way to do this in Scene Builder is to go into Miscellaneous, add a 'Group' or 'Region' and in the Document Hierarchy drag every label and node you want screenshotted into that group. You could also use anything under 'Containers' but those have other formatting to them that Group doesn't really have. Give the Group an fx:id and in your java code call `snapshot` on the Group. It's literally that easy.

Comment: All of the labels and images are children to the anchor pane. This is what it looks like in the .FXML file:
<AnchorPane .....>
    <children>
         <ImageView .......>

Comment: so then change your FXML, @WillA. There's a really convenient built in for this if you do, I don't see the need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: how would I change my FXML, can you link me something that would show me? @MMAdams

Comment: also, I would like to take a snapshot of part of the scene/AnchorPane rather than the nodes, is this possible? @MMAdams